# Ubuntu Tablet Programs

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I am thinking of buying the new Ubuntu tablet, but I am not sure exactly what will run on the device.

My questions are:

1. Is there a complete list of programs that will work on the tablet?
2. Will command line apps like the PAL calendar and todo.txt, and graphicsmagik run?  That is, can I also expect my BASH scripts to run?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of some of the prominent programs that are expected to have native support for touch:

http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/features

The input in Ubuntu Touch (15) is enabled by a mix of QT5 for the touch bit and Maliit for the virtual keyboard.  Telephony(cellular) is enabled is inherited via pieces contributed by Nokia to the Maemo and Meego projects.

Basically any app that runs on Linux should be supported... however their desktop GUI may not work well with input stack.

Ubuntu Touch tablets do support microUSB keyboards and microHDMI output to large monitors, turning your tablet into a desktop, though.  This way you can still use programs whose GUIs are well suited for touch at the present.

As it is Linux and has no manufacturer restrictions against the device owner's permissions (jailbroken Android), you can certainly run and install apps in the terminal -- even ones that require root.

BASH scripts will assuredly run, as well!

There's currently no Ubuntu Touch tablets on the market, but that will soonc change, as your comment suggests you may know.  The Aquarius Touch 10 by BQ is currently in preorder... it's somewhat pricey, but I guess that's the price you pay for early adoption:

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/aquaris-m10-ubuntu-edition-tablet.html

It ships (supposedly) the second week in April.  Hardware is a solid "meh" but the cool factor of a popular Linux distro on a tablet perhaps makes up for the price and hardware.